# In react, when radio buttons are unclickable, what are the common reasons?

Tags: reactjs

How can I detect the reason?

```
const [controllerStatus, setControllerStatus] = useState('10');


 const ControllerStatusList = [
    { result: "1.text1", value: 18 },
    { result: "2.text2", value: 10 },
  ];

<form>
       
        {ControllerStatusList.map((status1Obj, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id={`status1${index + 1}`}
              name="controllerStatusInput"
              value={status1Obj.value} // Use value instead of stageObj.stage
              checked={controllerStatus === status1Obj.value.toString()} // Update the comparison
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor={`status${index + 1}`}>
              {`${status1Obj.result}`} {/* Update to status1Obj.stage */}
            </label>
            <br />
          </div>
        ))}

      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show `handleInputChange` function? How is it setting `controllerStatus`?

You can set `controllerStatus` to the clicked checkbox value.
Here's a working example:

```js
const App = (props) => {

  const [controllerStatus, setControllerStatus] = React.useState("1");

  // Mock data
  const data = [
    { value: "1", result: "Hello" },
    { value: "2", result: "World" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((status1Obj, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id={`status1${index + 1}`}
              name={`controllerStatusInput-${index}`}
              value={status1Obj.value} // Use value instead of stageObj.stage
              checked={controllerStatus === status1Obj.value.toString()} // Update the comparison
              onChange={() => {
                // Set status1Obj value as selected
                setControllerStatus(status1Obj.value);
              }}
            />
            <label htmlFor={`status${index + 1}`}>
              {`${status1Obj.result}`} {/* Update to status1Obj.stage */}
            </label>
            <br />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

[image: Edit kind-waterfall-xd87cq]

Comment: It doesn't work on my computer.

Comment: The example does not work? 
Have you tried incognito mode? 
could it be an extension? 
Does HTML radio buttons work? -> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_radio